# discord.js canvas image manipulation

Tags: discord, discord.js, node-canvas

I wan't to make a command that put the user avatar in my wanted image

```js
    const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
    const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
    const Command = require('../../structures/Command')

    module.exports = class extends Command {
        constructor(client) {
            super(client, {
                name: 'wanted',
                description: 'Coloca a cabeça de um usuário valendo $2000.',
                options: [
                    {
                        name: 'user',
                        description: 'Usuário que terá a cabeça posta num cartaz de procurado',
                        type: 'USER',
                        required: true
                    }
                ]
            })
        }

        run = async (interaction) => {
            const canvas = createCanvas(239, 338)
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            const wantedImg = await loadImage("imgs/wanted.png")
            const userAv = interaction.options.getUser('user')
            const Avatar = userAv.avatarURL()
            interaction.reply(wantedImg)
        }
    }
```

I put the wantedImg in interaction.reply to see if the client return in chat the wanted image, but it's getting error...

> Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\pulse\OneDrive\Documentos\Cynthia\JS\src\commands\imgs\imgs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) instead:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() //get The first user mentioned
if (!user) return message.reply("Who is wanted?")//return if no user was mentioned

var wantedImage = "wanted image url goes here"
var pfp = user.avatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true, size: 128 }) //Get link of profile picture
var image = await Jimp.read(pfp)//read the profile picture, returns a Jimp object

//Composite resized bars on profile picture
image.composite((await Jimp.read(bars)).resize(128, 128), 0, 0)

//Create and attachment using buffer from edited picture and sending it
var image = new Discord.MessageAttachment(await image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_PNG))

message.reply(image) //replies to original command with image
```

It has far more options than canvas.

Comment: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp

Comment: This is due to you using an image that is not a png.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your path is correct, it seems that the path won't get resolved correctly. To be sure about your paths, consider using.

```
const {join} = require("path");

const wantedImg = loadImage(join(__dirname, "imgs/wanted.png"));
```